# Aligning divs inside a td

Tags: html, css

I would like to align via CSS the following div elements inside a td.
I have:

```
<table>
<tr>
<td style="width:300px;height:300px">

<div id="div1">hor+ver center alignment</div>
<div id="div2">top right</div>
<div id="div3">bottom left</div>

</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Can you please help me to prepare a stylesheet for this?
I've tried with inline-block display, but without a good result.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ok, this may be an overkill, but here it is:
First of all I'd suggest you wrap them with another `div` just to have a little more control

```
<table>
<tr>
<td style="width:300px;height:300px">
<div class="wrapper">
<div id="div1">hor+ver center alignment</div>
<div id="div2">top right</div>
<div id="div3">bottom left</div>
</div>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Then the styles:

```
.wrapper {
    position: relative;
    height:100%;
    text-align: center;
}
.wrapper:after {
    height:100%;
    content:'';
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
#div1,#div2,#div3 {
    display: inline-block;
}
#div1 {
    vertical-align: middle;
}
#div2 {
    position:absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
}
#div3 {
    position:absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
}
```

the `vertical-align:middle` trick I personaly love and use a lot, and some absolute positioning.

And here's the demo http://jsfiddle.net/pavloschris/vVHvd/

Comment: very good example, works perfectly. The only doubt I had was :after in ie8, but seems like it works

Comment: Thanks a lot, it worked perfectly. Thanks also to the other guys, but I needed a solution working in Firefox too.

Answer (score 0):

Like this **[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/3hhSP/)**?

```
#div1 {
    text-align:center;
}
#div2 {
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    right:0;
}
#div3 {
    position:absolute;
    bottom:0;
    left:0;
}
td, table {
    border:1px solid #999;
}
td {
    position:relative;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing the width of the first div, it's not going to be possible to pull off dynamically set horizontal alignment. It should automatically center vertically.

For the rest, you can use `absolute` positioning, like so:

```
<td style="width:300px;height:300px;position: relative;">

<div id="div1">hor+ver center alignment</div>
<div id="div2" style="position: absolute;top: 0px;right: 0px;">top right</div>
<div id="div3" style="position: absolute;bottom: 0px;left: 0px;">bottom left</div>

</td>
```